# How did the hostages know they were taken by the Vespers?

Tags: the-39-clues

In Cahills vs Vespers, book 4: Shatterproof, the hostages are aware that their captors are Vespers.

In one passage here:

> Alistair Oh would have given anything for a bite of one of his steak burritos and a sip of something refreshing. Instead he was holding a cold baked potato and a paper cup with four ounces of murky water. **The Vespers** had shut off the hostages’ water and reduced their food ration in retaliation for the recent escape attempt.

That doesn't prove that they knew, but later ones are more explicit:

> Reagan scrambled up behind Nellie like a monkey and handed her the pistol. “There’s one round left. Pass it up and tell Phoenix to make it count and to hurry. **The Vespers** will be here any second!”

And in Nellie's thoughts:

> *If **the Vespers** could murder a completely innocent bystander, what do they have in mind for us?*

Glancing through book one again, I didn't see any place where they were told or figured out who their captors were. So how did they know?

Answer (score -1):

They were informed that the Vespers were coming, so they assumed the Vespers were their captors.